# How to prevent user form ignoring suggestion in angularjs angular-ui-bootstrap uib-typeahead

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I am using AngularJS v1.6.6 and angular-ui-bootstrap Version: 2.5.0 to create an autocomplete field.

It all works correctly but I need a way to be sure that the user actually selects the option from the list of suggestions.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class='container-fluid typeahead-demo' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
<h4>How to prevent user from typing the whole word ignoring suggestions?</h4>
<div>Model: 
<pre>{{selected | json}}</pre>
</div>
<form role="form" name="chooseStateForm" autocomplete="off" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group required">
        <div>
            <label for="state" class="control-label col-sm-3">Choose a State:</label>
                <input type="text" 
                        class="form-control" 
                        required 
                        placeholder="Try typing the whole name of the state ignoring suggestion" 
                        name="state" 
                        ng-model="selected" 
                        uib-typeahead="option as option.name for option in states | filter:{name: $viewValue}" 
                        typeahead-min-length="1" 
                        typeahead-no-results="noresults" 
                        typeahead-show-hint="true" 
                        >
        </div>
        <div ng-if="noresults">
        <p>No match found!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<br><br><br><br>
<div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.ok()" ng-disabled="chooseStateForm.$invalid">OK</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('app').controller('TypeaheadCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.selected = undefined;
$scope.states = [
{id: 1, name: 'Alabama'},  
{id: 2, name: 'California'}, 
{id: 3, name: 'Delaware'}, 
{id: 4, name: 'Florida'}, 
{id: 5, name: 'Georgia'}, 
{id: 6, name: 'Hawaii'}, 
{id: 7, name: 'Idaho'},  
{id: 8, name: 'Kansas'}, 
{id: 9, name: 'Louisiana'}, 
{id: 10, name: 'Maine'}, 
{id: 11, name: 'Nebraska'}, 
{id: 12, name: 'Ohio'}, 
{id: 13, name: 'Pennsylvania'}, 
{id: 14, name: 'Rhode Island'}, 
{id: 15, name: 'South Carolina'}, 
{id: 16, name: 'Tennessee'},
{id: 17, name: 'Utah'}, 
{id: 18, name: 'Vermont'}, 
{id: 19, name: 'Washington'}
];
});
```

See this jsfiddle and you will understand what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/elenat82/yhpbdvva/20/

If the user wants, for example, to choose Ohio, since it is only 4 letters he could find it easier to just type "Ohio" than to choose the suggested option.

But doing this my model becomes a string whilst it is an object if he chooses from the suggestions list.

Yes I check the validity of the model in my controller but I want it to be done before the user submits the form, I would like to show an error message explaining to the user what he did wrong.

---------- EDIT ----------

I found another way to achieve the same result but using a directive and extending  the $validators object.

Here is the link to the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/elenat82/fL5fw1up/2/

And here is the updated code:

HTML:

```
<div class='container-fluid typeahead-demo' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
<h4>How to prevent user from typing the whole word ignoring suggestions?</h4>
<div>Model: 
<pre>{{selected | json}}</pre>
<div>Errors: 
<pre>{{chooseStateForm.state.$error | json}}</pre>
</div>
<form role="form" name="chooseStateForm" autocomplete="off" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group required">
        <div>
            <label for="state" class="control-label col-sm-3">Choose a State:</label>
                <input type="text" 
                        class="form-control" 
                        required 
                        placeholder="Try typing the whole name of the state ignoring suggestion" 
                        name="state" 
                        ng-model="selected" 
                        uib-typeahead="option as option.name for option in states | filter:{name: $viewValue}" 
                        typeahead-min-length="1" 
                        typeahead-no-results="noresults" 
                        typeahead-show-hint="true" 
                        object
                        >
        </div>
        <div ng-if="noresults">
        <p>No match found!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<br><br><br><br>
<div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.ok()" ng-disabled="chooseStateForm.$invalid">OK</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('app').controller('TypeaheadCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.selected = undefined;
$scope.states = [
{id: 1, name: 'Alabama'},  
{id: 2, name: 'California'}, 
{id: 3, name: 'Delaware'}, 
{id: 4, name: 'Florida'}, 
{id: 5, name: 'Georgia'}, 
{id: 6, name: 'Hawaii'}, 
{id: 7, name: 'Idaho'},  
{id: 8, name: 'Kansas'}, 
{id: 9, name: 'Louisiana'}, 
{id: 10, name: 'Maine'}, 
{id: 11, name: 'Nebraska'}, 
{id: 12, name: 'Ohio'}, 
{id: 13, name: 'Pennsylvania'}, 
{id: 14, name: 'Rhode Island'}, 
{id: 15, name: 'South Carolina'}, 
{id: 16, name: 'Tennessee'},
{id: 17, name: 'Utah'}, 
{id: 18, name: 'Vermont'}, 
{id: 19, name: 'Washington'}
];
});


angular.module('app').directive('object', [function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

        ngModel.$validators.object = function(modelValue,viewValue){
            if (angular.isObject(modelValue)) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
          };
    }
};

}
]);
```

Comment: Make a `<select><option>` ?

Comment: I can't, the clients wants an autocomplete field

Comment: in that case, how do you want to _force_ the user to click on one of the suggestion instead of typing? I'm talking from a UX point of view, not technical. If you put yourself in the end user's shoes, imagine having a free text field with suggestions, how could you be _forced_ to stop typing and click one of the suggestions? Doesn't sound realistic or user-friendly to me

Comment: That's the point! It is not a free text field, the user can't type what he wants, he has to choose from the list! The autocomplete field aims at avoiding the user browsing through hundreds of options in a select list when he already knows what he wants to select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add method for this validation for example:

```
$scope.isSelected = function() {
    return typeof $scope.selected == "object";
}
```

Comment: Where do I run this function? In an ng-change directive put in the input tag?

Comment: For example you can keep "OK" button disabled changing this "chooseStateForm.$invalid" to this "chooseStateForm.$invalid || !isSelected()". Another way is to use some element like span with information: "Pick value from the list" and set ng-show value to this method. All depend on requirements how the user want to be informed about this.I changed you example: http://jsfiddle.net/yhpbdvva/21/

Comment: Thank you Arkadiusz, you solved my problem both from a technical and from a user-experience point of view

Answer (score 1):

There is a property called `typeahead-editable="false"`.
If you set it to false, it will not allow the user to "not" choose something, the textbox will be set to empty.

Link: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#typeahead

> typeahead-editable $  (Default: true) - Should it restrict model values to the ones selected from the popup only?

http://jsfiddle.net/yhpbdvva/25/

Comment: Thank you Jens, it works and your answer is totally correct, but I just don't like the user experience it brings, I think Arkadiusz's and svarog's answers suit my needs a little bit better.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to traverse your array and check if the selected value (ngModel) exists on that array. You can define such a function and call it using [`ngChange`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange), that will run when you change your value

```
<input type="text" 
     class="form-control" 
     required
     name="state" 
     ng-model="selected" 
     .....
     ng-change="testIncluded(selected)">
```

And inside the controller, do something like this (using [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find))

```
$scope.testIncluded = function(value) {
    let isSelectedFromStates = $scope.states.find((state) => {
        return state.name === value;
    })
    /// do something ...
}
```

If the name exists, `isSelectedFromStates` will not be undefined

Comment: Thank you svarog, you answer is similar to the one I accepted, I would have not been able to find the solution by myself!